# Make [resample] a synonym of [resampling]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

[resampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resampling) is a fairly small tag with [662 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resampling), but has been around for a long time.

[resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resample) seems to have been created [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58618885/revisions) on October 30th this year. It had collected [15 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resample) in those 2 months, which I’ve retagged. It seemed best to nip this issue in the bud before it got worse.

However, do we need to do something to prevent the tag from being used again? Should we make it a synonym? Or can we hope it will disappear on its own from here on?